# Connect Raspi to touch display via I2C

Tags: i2c, raspbian-buster, touchscreen, input-device

I have a touch display with a microcontroller. That microcontroller will read the touch data and convert it [linux multi touch protocol](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/input/multi-touch-protocol.rst) and send to raspi via I2c.

Hardware is setup properly. Raspi can receive I2C data by using python-smbus.
How can I register this I2c as input device so I can interact with raspi by touch screen?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the README file in `/boot/firmware/README`? It's got a list of all overlays - you need to find the one that works w/ your hardware. Also, what OS Version?

Comment: I do not have /boot/firmware directory. My version is Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Comment: Sorry - I meant to say `/boot/overlays/README`

Comment: Thanks, i will go through that doc

Comment: You can try searching (e.g. if you open README in `less`) for strings that might help narrow things down; e.g. a model #, part of a name ("touch"), etc.